# Converting calculation contained in string to integer - C++

Tags: c++, string

I was wondering if it would be possible to store caluclations contained in a string to integer. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string variable = "-123+432";
cout << stoi(variable) << endl;
}
```

This returns -123, would it be possible to make it return 309?
Also what if there would be more calculations inside the string (eg. "-123+432*2"), and the person writing program would not know how many calculations will there be in a string (eg. string would be entered by user when the programm is runing). 
Thanks for all answers

Comment: You are going to wat to read up on reverse polish notation and the shunting yard algorithm.  That will help you build a parser that can tokenize the expression and allow you to evaluate it.

Comment: The C++ standard library does not include runtime evaluation of mathematical expressions expressed in a string.  You would need to find a library that can do this or write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible for sure, but it's quite complicated to parse arbitrary strings, work out if they contain a valid mathematical expression and then work out the result.

Unless you are wanting to implement the solution yourself for fun, I would suggest looking up and using a 3rd party library that evaluates string expressions, for example https://github.com/cparse/cparse

This would allow you to do something like (probably not exactly correct, just for rough example):

```
int main()
{
string variable = "-123+432";
std::cout << calculator::calculate(variable, &vars) << std::endl;
}
```

If you are wanting to do this yourself for fun, I suggest you look up "Expression evaluation" and start from there. It's quite a large and complicated topic but a lot of fun to write your own evaluator imo.